# Creating sub sections in the Table of Contents in iText pdf

Tags: java, itext

Hi I created a PDF with Table of contents with given example in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108090). But unfortunately I have no clue for doing it with sub sections in the TOC. I want structure like this

[image]

so please help me out. Thanks in advance